# Is a PTE Home B1 test sufficient for a UK Skilled Worker visa application?

Tags: united-kingdom, working-visas, language-test

I am about to apply for a **UK Skilled Worker visa**.

For that I need to prove proficiency in English, and I chose Pearson as one of the designated providers of English tests. Pearson provides, among others, the following two tests:

- PTE Home B1 (cheaper, takes about 30 minutes),
- PTE Academic UKVI (more expensive, takes about 3 hours).

> **Question**: Is passing a PTE Home B1 test sufficient for a Skilled Worker visa application?

Given all the circumstances (costs, duration, but also the date and location of the tests) I would really prefer to go with PTE Home B1 if possible.

---

I find that there is contradictory information around on this.

GOV.UK states that they [accept PTE Home tests](https://www.gov.uk/guidance/prove-your-english-language-abilities-with-a-secure-english-language-test-selt#find-an-approved-test), and that a Skilled Worker visa application [requires a proof of proficiency on level B1](https://www.gov.uk/skilled-worker-visa/knowledge-of-english).
However, the first statement appears on a site not specific to the a Skilled Worker visa, and could as well mean that *some* visa types allow a PTE Home test (e.g. spouse visa require only PTE Home A1). The Skilled Worker specific site is not talking about PTE Home.

Pearson [recommends PTE Academic UKVI](https://pearsonpte.com/uk/ukvisas) for this kind of visa.

---

I have contacted several parties with this question:

- The UK Visa and Immigration International Contact Center replied with a generic answer copied from [here](https://www.gov.uk/guidance/prove-your-english-language-abilities-with-a-secure-english-language-test-selt#find-an-approved-test) (the same link as above), not explicitly talking about the Skilled Worker visa or PTE Home B1. They says, *Yes*, PTE Home is okay, but the wording gives me doubt about their understanding of my specific question.
- The HR Immigration Support Team at my future working place replied that I need the PTE Academic UKVI, but gave no further reason. Note that they do not care about any tests themselves (i.e. I do not have to prove my language abilities to them), but they only care about me having the visa.
- Pearson themselves replied with a generic copy from their FAQ, stating that PTE Academic is appropriate. I consider this a non-answer, because it says nothing about whether PTE Home B1 is suitable or not. Given that they make a profit of selling more expensive tests, I am skeptical about this answer.

Comment: Any update on this? I am in the same situation?

Comment: @user27448 In the end I did not require the test since I went with a different visa type (Global Talent). But if I would need to do a test I would probably trust the answer of xngtng below.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> However, the first statement appears on a site not specific to the a Skilled Worker visa, and could as well mean that some visa types allow a PTE Home test (e.g. spouse visa require only PTE Home A1).

You are correct. The exact requirements differ, both on the level needed and the skills assessed.

> PTE Home B1 (cheaper, takes about 30 minutes)
>
> PTE Academic UKVI (more expensive, takes about 3 hours).

The most important difference between the two tests: PTE Home does not test reading and writing skills, both of which must be proved in addition to listening and speaking skills for a Skilled Worker visa.

> You must prove you can **read, write, speak and understand** English to at least level B1 on the Common European Framework of Reference for Languages (CEFR) scale.
>
> https://www.gov.uk/skilled-worker-visa/knowledge-of-english

The list of approved tests available on the [other page](https://www.gov.uk/guidance/prove-your-english-language-abilities-with-a-secure-english-language-test-selt#find-an-approved-test) contains information on whether a test is 2-facet (oral skills only) or 4-facet (all four skills).

Thus, for skilled worker visas, the PTE Home test alone is not enough. You should take the Academic one (or other approved f-facet tests).